# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query, can not active transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am facing a problem when I use spring mvc and hibernate transaction, 
I am try to use my dao with HQL to update database then server throw a TransactionRequiredException, I've  checked my transaction annotation, ComponentScan, and the transaction package, every method of service are working fine but the updateStock method.

Does anyone have same or similar problem about this?

there is my code:

Dispatcher:

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    productService pService;
    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;
    @Autowired
    orderService oService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ConfirmOrder")
    public String ConfirmOrder(HttpSession session) {
        shoppingCart sc = (shoppingCart) session.getAttribute("shoppingCart");
        orderBean ob = (orderBean) session.getAttribute("orderList");
        Set<orderItemBean> items = new HashSet<orderItemBean>();
        Map<Integer, orderItem> cart = sc.getContent();
        Set<Integer> set = cart.keySet();
        Integer newStock = 0;
        int n = 0;
        productBean mb = null;
        for (Integer k : set) {
            orderItem oi = cart.get(k);
            Integer subtotal = (oi.getiQty() * oi.getpPrice());
            String iDes = oi.getpName() + " 共 " + oi.getiQty().toString() + "個，金額小計:" + subtotal.toString();
            orderItemBean oib = new orderItemBean(null, oi.getpId(), iDes, oi.getiQty(), oi.getpPrice());
            oib.setOrderBean(ob);
            items.add(oib);
            mb = pService.getProduct(oi.getpId());
            newStock = mb.getpInstock() - oi.getiQty();
            n = pService.updateStock(oi.getpId(), newStock); //throw exception from here
        }
        ob.setItemSet(items);
        oService.saveOrder(ob);
        session.removeAttribute("shoppingCart");
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import config.GlobalService;
import product.Dao.productDao;
import product.model.productBean;

@Repository
public class productDaoImpl implements productDao {
    int pageNo = 0;
    SessionFactory factory;

    public SessionFactory getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public productDaoImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public int updateStock(int pId, int newStock) {
        int n = 0;
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        String sql = "UPDATE productBean b SET b.pInstock = :stock WHERE b.pId = :id";
        n = session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("stock", newStock).setParameter("id", pId).executeUpdate();
        return n;
    }

}
```

service:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import config.GlobalService;
import product.Dao.productDao;
import product.model.productBean;
import product.service.productService;

@Transactional
@Service
public class productServiceImpl implements productService {
    productDao pdao;
    SessionFactory factory;

    public productDao getPdao() {
        return pdao;
    }

    public SessionFactory getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setPdao(productDao pdao) {
        this.pdao = pdao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public productServiceImpl() {

    }

    @Override
    public List<productBean> getAllProduct() {
        List<productBean> list = null;
        list = pdao.getAllProduct();
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public int insertNewProduct(productBean pb) {
        int n = 0;
        pdao.insertNewProduct(pb);
        n++;
        return n;
    }

    @Override
    public productBean getProduct(int pId) {
        productBean pb = null;
        pb = pdao.getProduct(pId);
        return pb;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPageNo(int pageNo) {
        pdao.setPageNo(pageNo);

    }

    @Override
    public int getPageNo() {
        return pdao.getPageNo();
    }

    @Override
    public int getTotalPages() {
        int totalPages = (int) (Math.ceil(getDataCount() / (double) GlobalService.dataPerPage));
        return totalPages;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getDataCount() {

        return pdao.getDataCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int updateStock(int pId, int newStock) {
        return pdao.updateStock(pId, newStock);
    }

}
```

WebAppConfig:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "dispatcherController, register, product, cart, checkout")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resource/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resource/img/");
    }

    public WebAppConfig() {

    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setMaxUploadSize(81920000);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

RootAppConfig:

```
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RootAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        ds.setUser("sa");
        ds.setPassword("sa123456");
        try {
            ds.setDriverClass("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=PDB");
        ds.setInitialPoolSize(4);
        ds.setMaxPoolSize(8);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "product.model","register.model","cart.model" });
        factory.setHibernateProperties(additionalProperties());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect.class);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", Boolean.TRUE);
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", Boolean.TRUE);
        properties.put("default_batch_fetch_size", 10);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

WebInitializer:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RootAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Comment: You really, really need to read [the Spring MVC reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html), a Spring Boot Getting Started Guide, and information on Spring Data JPA; nearly everything you wrote here Spring will do for you automatically. (You should also review the [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), which matches industry standards.)

Comment: I found the solution that just change @EnableTransactionManagement annotation from RootAppConfig to WebAppConfig then it works, but I still don't know why.